# Suggestion for way foward with upregulated genes

Tags: rna-seq, scrnaseq, ngs, cancer, pathway

I am working with single cell RNA data- control and treated. I analyzed and got a list of upregulated genes. Upon doing pathway analysis all the genes were of apoptotic pathway. But these genes can signify different meaning to my interpretation, because, these genes were upregulated even in diseased condition. let me take an example, NEAT1 is one of the gene that is seen upregulated in the cancer condition and is associated with cancer progression. the treated sample which is a therapy also has neat1 upregulated compared to control which was untreated. Just because pathway analysis showed apoptosis, I cannot conclude that neat1 gene is aiding in killing the cancer cell due to the therapy right/ It can also be like due to continued upregulation its delaying cancer cell death due to therpay.

How to confirm computationally the above two statements and find the upregulated genes actual role in the therapy?
to be noted: there is no prior data or pattern available for the therapy based gene expression yet.